# PYTHON: How should I change my code to reorganize files by day rather than by month?

Tags: python

I've got a bit of code that renames and reorganizes NetCDF files into monthly folders. I would like to change this code so that it gives me daily folders rather than monthly folders.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

destination_directory = input("Now please provide the destination directory in the same format:")

wd = os.chdir(destination_directory)
for f in os.listdir():
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    f_1, f_2, date = file_name.split('.')
    dt = datetime.strptime(date,"%Y%m%d%H%M")
    newname = "{}{}{}{}.{}".format(str(dt.year),str(dt.month),str(dt.day),str(dt.time().hour)+str(dt.time().minute),'nc')
    dst = os.path.join(str(dt.year),str(dt.month),newname)
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(str(dt.year),str(dt.month))) == False:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(str(dt.year),str(dt.month)))
    os.rename(f, dst)
    print(dst, newname, 'created')
```

Comment: You use `os.path.join(str(dt.year),str(dt.month)` 3 times, please save it in a variable ;)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to add day to your paths. Like this:

```
dst = os.path.join(str(dt.year),str(dt.month),str(dt.day),newname)
if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(str(dt.year),str(dt.month),str(dt.day))) == False:
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(str(dt.year),str(dt.month),str(dt.day)))
```